# How to define generc to FC component in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

What syntax to pass type to Interface Props generic?
(Cat must be type FC)

```
interface CatProps<T> {
  value: T
}

const Cat: FC<CatProps<T>> = () => {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
}

const cat = <Cat<number> />
```

[image]

Comment: Please [avoid images of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and instead provide a [mcve] as preformatted text block in your question description.

Comment: Try `const Cat = <T extends any>(props: CatProps<T>) => <h1>Hello World!</h1>`

Comment: @Alex Chashin but this not FC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example (based on @Alex Chashin's comment):

```
interface CatProps<T> {
  value: T;
}

const Cat = <T extends any>({value}: CatProps<T>) => <h1>Hello {value}!</h1>

const cat = Cat({value: 'world'});
```

or if you want to pass a number:

```
const cat = Cat({value: 11});
```

Comment: But in your example Cat it is not FC

Comment: It's not, but it's assignable to one, that's all that matters. You can't type it using the `FC` type, because you need to attach the type parameter to the function itself, and you cannot use `T` outside of the function, where you would put `FC`